# Copy Updated Database into device in ios sdk

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, database, xcode

In my app, i used the sqlite DB. I submitted the 1.0 version of the app to app store. But after that i made some changes into DB like Inserting some new rows.

Then submitted 1.1 version of the app. `But i will not able to get updated DB because the old DB already exists in device.`

**How can i solve this?**

If i delete the app & then install the new version of app, then i got the updated DB.

```
//My code for copy of DB is as follow:

- (void)createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded
{
    // First, test for existence.
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *writableDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xxx.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if (success) return;

    // The writable database does not exist, so copy the default to the appropriate location.

    NSString *defaultDBPath = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xxx.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager copyItemAtPath:defaultDBPath toPath:writableDBPath error:&error];
    if (!success) {
        NSAssert1(0, @"Failed to create writable database file with message '%@'.", [error localizedDescription]);
    }
}
```

*I called this method in appDidFinishLaunching method.*

**How can i get updated DB without deleting the app when new version is available**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/Reference/Reference.html) for doing this.

In your new version add this code:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"1.1"]])
  {
     [self removeDatabase];
     [self createEditableCopyOfDatabaseIfNeeded];
     [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"1.1"];
  }
  //Other stuffs
}
```

Method for removing the old database file:

```
- (void)removeDatabase
{
    BOOL success;
    NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
    NSError *error;
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString *removeDBPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"xxx.sqlite"];
    success = [fileManager fileExistsAtPath:writableDBPath];
    if(success)
    {
       [fileManager removeItemAtPath:writableDBPath error:&error]
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Wow, what a great idea to doing this very easily.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to perform a database migration so that old users of your app do not lose their data.

This means checking which version of the database already exists, and executing the necessary SQL statements to update the schema and data.

The [MTMigration](https://github.com/mysterioustrousers/MTMigration) framework (MIT license) can help you execute code once per version of your app, for example:

```
[MTMigration migrateToVersion:@"1.1" block:^{
    // migrate the SQL database here
}];
```

But you may wish to detect the version of your database differently.

It would be a good idea to write some unit tests for this procedure. Screwing up user data is the last thing you want to do.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! So, should i write the all queries programmatically?

Comment: You can either put the SQL directly in your source code, or keep it in .sql files for easier management which you then load at runtime.

Comment: So,According to you, if i want to insert some new rows in DB, I must executes new queries programmetically instead of just add directly in sql DB.

Comment: Why are you copying the database to the documents directory in the first place? Is this a fixed, static database or something the user can edit? If it's static, you can just directly open it from the app bundle and you avoid all these problems.

Comment: If i can't copy the DB in Document at first place then every time when app is launch, the user may loose the previous history which is generated during the interaction. That's why i make a copy of DB once when user install the app.

Comment: OK, so since the user modifies the DB you need to do what I've said which is to migrate stuff. If you have "default" data which can change, you may want to look at using core data where you can merge two separate database files into one context.

Comment: I don't know anything about core data.

Answer (score 0):

You have to write Data migration script:-

In case when you need to make changes to an exiting table which contains some data then you need to do some steps as follows:

1) Rename the existing table

Say TableName was 'TestTable', So Rename the table to 'TestTableOld'

2) Create a new table called 'TestTable' which has the new columns you want and other altercations made.

3) Copy data from 'TestTableOld' to 'TestTable' with the query like:

Insert into TestTable('col1',col2'...'coln') Values Select col1, col2, col3,...'coln' From TestTableOld;

And newly added column set value as blank, as for new entries will use as such.

4) Drop the table 'TestTableOld'

Follow the above four step procedure as this would work as an alter statement and also it would preserve all your data from your original table.

If you are using User_Version, then would helpfull to identify old DB with new DB